# Can not reach object properties via dataProvider

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to reach object propherties but something is happening. Can realize why i get non-object error. I did this many times but now it doesnt work. Please guys give me an advice!

```
if($comments)
{
    echo '<ul class="gridProduct col-md-12 pr0 pl0" style="min-height: 350px;">';
    foreach ($comments as $comment)
    {
        $user_comment = Testimonial::findOne($comment['id']);

        echo '<div class="col-md-6 item">
            <div class="vk-testimonial">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <div class="vk-img-frame">
                            <a href="#" class="vk-img">
                                <img src="' . Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/testimonials/'  . $user_comment->filename . '" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile">
                            <span class="name">' . $user_comment->name . '</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                        <p class="vk-text">' . $user_comment->text . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<nav class="box-pagination">';
    echo LinkPager::widget([
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'nextPageCssClass' => 'remove-margin-left',
        'maxButtonCount' => 2
    ]);
    echo '</nav>';
}
```

Controller action:

```
$pageSize = 6;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `testimonial` LEFT JOIN `testimonialLang` ON `testimonial`.`id`=`testimonialLang`.`testimonial_id` WHERE active=1 AND `language`=\"" . $lang->url . "\"";

        $count = count(\Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll());

        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
           'sql' => $sql,
            'totalCount' => $count,
            'pagination' => [
                'pagesize' => $pageSize,
                'totalCount' => $count,
                'route' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('first_step'),
            ]
        ]);

        $pagination = new Pagination([
            'pagesize' => $pageSize,
            'totalCount' => $count,
            'route' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('first_step'),
        ]);

        $comments = $dataProvider->getModels();

        if(\Yii::$app->request->isPjax)
        {
            return $this->render('users-opinion', [
                'page' => $page,
                'comments' => $comments,
                'pagination' => $pagination,
                'lang' => $lang
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('users-opinion', [
            'page' => $page,
            'comments' => $comments,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
            'lang' => $lang
        ]);
```

I have `var_dump`it right before the `echo` in the view and its a real object with all the properties but in the `echo` I get:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: var_dump of what ???   .. please show you var:dump and the related  result  ..

Comment: `var_dump($user_comment->filename);die; `
result : string(14) `"nasko_13_1.jpg"`. The result i expected :) And 6 rows below it tells me `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: could be that you have empty or invalid value in $comments ... check better